# log files too big

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati

I have a lot of `kern.log` files with sizes of 10GB+ which have many lines similar to:

```
AMD-Vi : Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=01:00.0 domain=0x0014 address=0x0000000000001000 flags=0x0000]
```

A few days ago I upgraded my hardware to an AMD FX8300 CPU and a Nvidia 9800GT video card. The graphics drivers use are NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.65.

my `uname -a` is:

```
Linux timepower 3.18.1-031801-generic #201412170637 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:38:50 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And my `lshw` is in http://paste.ubuntu.com/9633122/

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the syslog settings being used.  I suspect that you are setting the level too low and getting too much information.  It could also be that you have a debug settings on the driver set.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running `memtest` which comes as an option in the GRUB menu or in any of the Ubuntu Live images. In regards to the huge log files, you can simply grab the important debug lines, like the one you mentioned and remove the files before they eat your space. 10GB log files is too much. I am guessing you are a Desktop user and not a server. In the case of the server, I would further analyze what errors the log is giving you and find answers to each specific problem.

In regards to the **Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT** I would again, check with `memtest` first, and then check your BIOS or UEFI to see what options could make this happened (Like virtual technology enabled/disabled, memory settings, cpu tunning and more)

Normally I find that it is either a bad memory on the computer or a misconfigured BIOS setting.

Comment: Thx, I use desktop(xubuntu), my memory is ok.
Motherboard use UEFI, Setting is very limited, and there is no virtual setting.